# v4l2 manual exposure not working compared to Windows 10

Tags: camera, raspbian, v4l2, webcam-capture, uvc

This question is very similar to [V4L2 absolute exposure setting has (almost) not effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61581125/v4l2-absolute-exposure-setting-has-almost-not-effect/)

I have a `UVC` compliant camera that I am running on a `Raspberry Pi CM3+` module. It appears as `video0`.

 Using the tools/drivers `v4l2-ctl`, `qv4l2` or `guvcview` the `absolute exposure` cannot be controlled, yet it can be controlled when using `Amcap` on Windows 10.

The camera has two exposure modes `manual` and `aperature controlled`. When in `aperature controlled` the exposure levels in the image change dynamically, however, when switched to `manual` mode the image becomes very dark and does not change whether at the upper or lower limit of the range which can be selected.

When running `v4l2-ctl` the range `min` is stated to be `5` and the `max` is `2500`. Yet in windows it is between `-2` and `-11` and the exposure of the image changes proportionally as you would expect.

Parameter range from `v4l2`:

```
exposure_auto 0x009a0901 (menu)       : min=0 max=3 default=3 value=1
exposure_absolute 0x009a0902 (int)    : min=5 max=2500 step=1 default=156 value=1659
```

Parameter range from `Amcap` on Windows 10:

[image: !(http://prntscr.com/whgwcf)]

If I do `v4l2-ctl -d0 -all` here is what I get:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ v4l2-ctl -d0 --all
Driver Info:
        Driver name      : uvcvideo
        Card type        : HD USB CAMERA: HD USB CAMERA
        Bus info         : usb-0000:01:00.0-1.3
        Driver version   : 5.4.79
        Capabilities     : 0x84a00001
                Video Capture
                Metadata Capture
                Streaming
                Extended Pix Format
                Device Capabilities
        Device Caps      : 0x04200001
                Video Capture
                Streaming
                Extended Pix Format
Media Driver Info:
        Driver name      : uvcvideo
        Model            : HD USB CAMERA: HD USB CAMERA
        Serial           : 01.00.00
        Bus info         : usb-0000:01:00.0-1.3
        Media version    : 5.4.79
        Hardware revision: 0x00000224 (548)
        Driver version   : 5.4.79
Interface Info:
        ID               : 0x03000002
        Type             : V4L Video
Entity Info:
        ID               : 0x00000001 (1)
        Name             : HD USB CAMERA: HD USB CAMERA
        Function         : V4L2 I/O
        Flags         : default
        Pad 0x01000007   : 0: Sink
          Link 0x02000013: from remote pad 0x100000a of entity 'Extension 4': Data, Enabled, Immutable
Priority: 2
Video input : 0 (Camera 1: ok)
Format Video Capture:
        Width/Height      : 640/480
        Pixel Format      : 'YUYV' (YUYV 4:2:2)
        Field             : None
        Bytes per Line    : 1280
        Size Image        : 614400
        Colorspace        : sRGB
        Transfer Function : Default (maps to sRGB)
        YCbCr/HSV Encoding: Default (maps to ITU-R 601)
        Quantization      : Default (maps to Limited Range)
        Flags             :
Crop Capability Video Capture:
        Bounds      : Left 0, Top 0, Width 640, Height 480
        Default     : Left 0, Top 0, Width 640, Height 480
        Pixel Aspect: 1/1
Selection: crop_default, Left 0, Top 0, Width 640, Height 480, Flags:
Selection: crop_bounds, Left 0, Top 0, Width 640, Height 480, Flags:
Streaming Parameters Video Capture:
        Capabilities     : timeperframe
        Frames per second: 30.000 (30/1)
        Read buffers     : 0
                     brightness 0x00980900 (int)    : min=-64 max=64 step=1 default=0 value=-6
                       contrast 0x00980901 (int)    : min=0 max=95 step=1 default=1 value=6
                     saturation 0x00980902 (int)    : min=0 max=100 step=1 default=52 value=22
                            hue 0x00980903 (int)    : min=-2000 max=2000 step=1 default=0 value=0
 white_balance_temperature_auto 0x0098090c (bool)   : default=1 value=0
                          gamma 0x00980910 (int)    : min=100 max=300 step=1 default=115 value=115
           power_line_frequency 0x00980918 (menu)   : min=0 max=2 default=1 value=1
      white_balance_temperature 0x0098091a (int)    : min=2800 max=6500 step=1 default=4600 value=4600
                      sharpness 0x0098091b (int)    : min=0 max=7 step=1 default=0 value=0
         backlight_compensation 0x0098091c (int)    : min=36 max=160 step=1 default=54 value=36
                  exposure_auto 0x009a0901 (menu)   : min=0 max=3 default=3 value=1
              exposure_absolute 0x009a0902 (int)    : min=5 max=2500 step=1 default=156 value=1659
error 22 getting ext_ctrl Pan (Absolute)
error 22 getting ext_ctrl Tilt (Absolute)
                 focus_absolute 0x009a090a (int)    : min=0 max=1023 step=1 default=0 value=355
                     focus_auto 0x009a090c (bool)   : default=1 value=0
error 22 getting ext_ctrl Zoom, Absolute
```

I have tried changing the format between `MJPEG` and `YUYV` without any change.

I am assuming that it a driver issue or some setting that I am overlooking?

Comment: Not sure why guvcview doesn't work. As for the difference of the absolute time values you see on Linux and Windows, it is because Windows shows it as 2^n seconds ([ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/stream/ksproperty-cameracontrol-exposure)) where n -2 to -11 in your case, if you do the calculation you will see they match the settings you see on Linux.

Comment: @dhanushka - thank you for the link, although I am unsure how to do the calculation? Do you think that Linux has a sweet spot in its range that I am missing?

Comment: @dhanushka - see my answer below. I am sure that you will be able to add some mathematical meaning to my findings?

Comment: I mean, you can calculate the abs exposure time for Linux from Windows values like this: suppose you set -4.5 on Windows. Corresponding value on Linux is (2^-4.5)*(10^6)us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amcap (Windows) in my case has 5 discrete exposure levels `[-6,-5,-4,-3,-2]`.

Linux (`guvcview` and `v4l2`) has a continuous range from `[5 to 2500]` (as can be seen in the OP using `v4l2-ctl`.

I have manually set the exposure levels in Amcap and then read them using Linux (`guvcview`): 
[-6 = 156; -5 = 312; -4 = 625; -3 = 1250; -2 = 2500]

When I set the `exposure` to any of these levels it works as expected. **HOWEVER** if I set any other values, for example, 2499 or 157, just one digit off I get nearly complete black!

I am sure there is some mathematical reason that will show this, however, I have found this misleading since the Linux drivers report a continuous range which suggests that the exposure range is linear, but it is not and is discrete!